# i want execute my previous days unexecute job first rather than today in Control-M

Tags: control-m

i am trying ordering my jobs into planing until jobs gets success,but when previous days jobs for that particular CTM table run then only today order jobs need to be run , i have added keep active for 10 days for each job.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an IN-CONDITION of the same job with PREV date, so that todays job will run only when yesterday's job has completed its run successfully.

If you want to run todays job even when yesterdays job fails, you can add a DO-STEP on failure, to create a condition which can be used by todays job to start running.